# SetBool doesn't save my boolean statements

Tags: unity-game-engine, boolean

How does one save boolean variables after I quit my game?

I tried using the PlayerPrefsX, from the unitywiki website but no success. I used it like this:

```
 showButton1 = false;
 PlayerPrefsX.SetBool("showButton1",showButton1);
```

And after this, when I restart the scene, I just load the boolean variable with GetBool on Start.

```
function Start()
{
    PlayerPrefsX.GetBool("showButton1");
}
```

Comment: BoolPrefs just simply convert the bool value to int (0 and 1). Have you tried to use PlayerPrefs without BoolPrefs and tested that it works?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm currently using it with my Highscore script, to load my highscores and save them. PlayerPrefs works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)?

Save

```
showButton1 = false;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("showButton1", showButton1 ? 1 : 0);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Load

```
showButton1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("showButton1") > 0;
```

Comment: +1: That's the simplest way to go. Btw the wiki script the OP is referring to does exactly this, so I guesss his bug should be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks to Jessys edit and Albertos answer, I now have a fully functionalized shop on my game. I don't know how to thank you. Thank you very much, to both of you.